# To get the whole line while using Mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Need experts help to get whole original line using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE and put into my db column

### Sample

**table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `syslog`;
CREATE TABLE `syslog` (
  `the_time` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `the_key` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `the_log` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**File : D:/rnd/syslog.csv**

```
"device","date_time","src_ip","dst_ip","log_type","message"
"Fortigate","2012-05-02 12:02:03","192.168.1.1","192.168.1.11","vpn","Sample message1"
"Fortigate","2012-05-02 12:02:04","192.168.1.2","192.168.1.12","vpn","Sample message2"
"Fortigate","2012-05-02 12:02:05","192.168.1.3","192.168.1.13","traffic","Sample message3"
"Fortigate","2012-05-02 12:02:06","192.168.1.4","192.168.1.14","traffic","Sample message4"
"Fortigate","2012-05-02 12:02:07","192.168.1.5","192.168.1.15","vpn","Sample message5"
"Fortigate","2012-05-02 12:02:08","192.168.1.6","192.168.1.16","vpn","Sample message6"
```

**Mysql Statement**

```
SET @delimeter = ",";
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
"D:/rnd/syslog.csv"
INTO TABLE syslog
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
( @device,
  @date_time,
  @src_ip,
  @dst_ip,
  @log_type,
  @message) 
SET the_time = @date_time, 
the_key=CONCAT(@src_ip, "~" , @dst_ip), 
the_log=CONCAT(@device,@delimeter,@date_time,@delimeter,@src_ip,@delimeter,@dst_ip,@delimeter,@log_type,@delimeter,@message);
```

Currently is is just working with manual setting like

```
the_log=CONCAT(@device,@delimeter,@date_time,@delimeter,@src_ip,@delimeter,@dst_ip,@delimeter,@log_type,@delimeter,@message)
```

Is there any other way to get the whole line since the actual column is 60 and it is not a good idea to do it manually inside the code + not easy to maintain later.

- Objective : To use the csv data and manipulate it into my own table (Means the column does not same as the csv)

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to create table structure as CSV-file, store data as is, and use CONCAT only when you SELECT data from log table.

Comment: this is my last choice since i need to process faster